# Trying to display facebook user's photo of unknown id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi Is it possible to display a user's photo. For example, 
From ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/ )

Using the graph api, photos can be displayed

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/mike.shaver/picture"/>
```

Is there any way I could say something like,

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/VISITOR/picture"/>
```

I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this. It was once possible with FBML but that method has since been deprecated and doesn't work anymore.

You'll have to have access to the users id in order to display this data.
In order to get the users id to display his basic information (profile picture for example), you'll have to request the [basic permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) from the user.

Comment: Hi Lix, Thanks for the answer. Enjoy an upvote. Follow up question: is there any facebook user data I can show without basic permissions? Thanks

Comment: @use - nope - that is the whole idea behind permissions. AFAIK, the only "data" you can get on users without permissions is if your application is a tab application.  In this case, you'll be able to know if the visiting users "likes" the page or not - but you still won't know who exactly it is...

Comment: @use - also please don't forget to use the `@` sign when using [comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) - that way the person you are referring to will get a notification...

Comment: @Lix You're pretty much limited to what you can pull from Facebook's signed request. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/